# Ocean Modifier Questions

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine, ocean-simulation

I have a few questions on how the *Ocean Modifier* works. They are for the *Blender Internal*,so please be specific.

1. What does the Foam Data Layer do in *Blender Internal*? Does it do anything?
2. Is the Ocean Texture associated with the *Ocean Modifier*? If so then is it a replacement for Foam Data Layer but for *Blender Internal*?

Thanks for clearing up the topic

Answer (score 2):

I assume that by "Blender Manual" you mean "Blender Internal".

The foam data layer is just an ordinary vertex color layer, you can see it in the object data, you can change it in the vertex paint mode, and Blender Internal can render it - see "Vertex Color Paint" and "Vertex Color Light" in Material/Options.